# scrapy download excel from site

Tags: python, scrapy

My goal is automatically downloading a specific excel file from a site.

I have a spider that finds relevant link to excel file and yields it to down the line pipeline.

The yield function in the spider is

```
def extracting_function():
    #do something  
    yield scrapy.Request(url=dl_path, callback=self.download_excel)

def download_excel(self, response):
    fn = response.url.split('/')[-1]
    self.logger.info('Saving EXL %s', fn)
    dl_item = DownloadItem(body=response.body, url=response.url)
    yield dl_item
```

The pipeline parse is:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dl_url = item['url']
    fn = dl_url.split('/')[-1]
    self.replace_and_save(item['body'], fn)
    return item

def replace_and_save(self, to_save, fn):
    o_fn = os.path.join(self.save_path, fn)
    ##replace
    if os.path.exists(o_fn):
        old_file = self.get_one_excel_df(o_fn)
        new_name = '{0}_{1}'.format(fn, datetime.datetime.today())
        with open(new_name, 'wb') as ouf:
            pickle.dump(ouf, old_file)
        print('Removing old file {0} after creating a backup version of it'.format(o_fn))
        os.remove(o_fn)

    with open(o_fn, 'wb') as ouf:
        ouf.write(to_save)
```

A file is being saved but it is not the xlsx file I intended but the page body(where I **scraped** the download link from).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: get this `response.url` and use in web browser. You can turn off JavaScript in browser before you try this url. And it could be easier if you put url for scraped paga so we could see it.

Comment: Yes - That was the issue! the respone.url was not what I thought it was. After fixing it - it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, rare are the occasions where need to bust out Selenium to get that rendered JS ! Splash is great but I feel like lower spec PCs, <8GB , kinda lag up a bit. Its much easier for me to use Selenium local... Having all that said, would be nice to have a server set up with scapyd and splash... on a kafka!? That sounds amazing.