# How to Automatically select data on webpage and download the resulting xls file using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation, scrapy

I am new to Python. I am trying to scrape the data on the [page](https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-config):

For example:

```
Category: grains  
Organic: No  
Commodity: Coarse  
SubCommodity: Corn  
Publications: Daily  
Location: All  
Refine Commodity: All

Dates: 07/31/2018 - 08/01/2019
```

Is there a way in which Python can select this on the webpage and then click on run and then

Click on Download as Excel and store the excel file?

Is it possible? I am new to coding and need some guidance here.

Currently what I have done is enter the data and then on the resulting page I used Beautiful Soup to scrape the table. However it takes a lot of time since the table is spread on more than 200 pages.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562839/scrapy-download-excel-from-site

Comment: Use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), and pass the URL to the Excel file as the first parameter.

Comment: @PyNoob But won't I have to generate the excel file? I wanted to automate it so that Python automatically selects the options and then download the excel file

Comment: @RaghavGoyal It seems like you just need to put the parameters in the URL, since all the parameters are passed via a GET request. I'll see if I can make an example for this.

Comment: @PyNoob Please. That would be of great, great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query you defined as an example, I input the query manually and found the following URL for the Excel (really HTML) format:

```py
url = 'https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain=08%2F01%2F2019&commDetail=All&repMonth=1&endDateWeekly=&repType=Daily&rtype=&fsize=&_use=1&use=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain=07%2F31%2F2018&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear=2019&repDateWeekly=&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2019&loc=All&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&organic=NO&category=Grain&_mscore=1&subComm=Corn&commodity=Coarse&_commDetail=1&_subprimals=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate=07%2F31%2F2018&endDate=08%2F01%2F2019&format=excel'
```

In the URL are parameters we can set in Python, and we could easily make a loop to change the parameters. For now, let me just get into the example of actually getting this data. I use the [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to read this HTML result and populate a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), which could be thought of as a table with columns and rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
#  use URL defined earlier
#  url = '...'
df_lst = pd.read_html(url, header=1)
```

Now `df_lst` is a list of DataFrame objects containing the desired data. For your particular example, this results in 30674 rows and 11 columns:

```py
>>> df_lst[0].columns
Index([u'Report Date', u'Location', u'Class', u'Variety', u'Grade Description',
       u'Units', u'Transmode', u'Low', u'High', u'Pricing Point',
       u'Delivery Period'],
      dtype='object')
>>> df_lst[0].head()
  Report Date         Location   Class  Variety Grade Description   Units   Transmode   Low  High         Pricing Point Delivery Period
0  07/31/2018  Blytheville, AR  YELLOW      NaN           US NO 2  Bushel       Truck  3.84  3.84     Country Elevators            Cash
1  07/31/2018       Helena, AR  YELLOW      NaN           US NO 2  Bushel       Truck  3.76  3.76     Country Elevators            Cash
2  07/31/2018  Little Rock, AR  YELLOW      NaN           US NO 2  Bushel       Truck  3.74  3.74  Mills and Processors            Cash
3  07/31/2018   Pine Bluff, AR  YELLOW      NaN           US NO 2  Bushel       Truck  3.67  3.67     Country Elevators            Cash
4  07/31/2018       Denver, CO  YELLOW      NaN           US NO 2  Bushel  Truck-Rail  3.72  3.72    Terminal Elevators            Cash
>>> df_lst[0].shape
(30674, 11)
```

---

Now, back to the point I made about the URL parameters--using Python, we can run through lists and format the URL string to our liking. For instance, iterating through 20 years of the given query can be done by modifying the URL to have numbers corresponding to positional arguments in Python's `str.format()` method. Here's a full example below:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain={1}&commDetail=All&repMonth=1&endDateWeekly=&repType=Daily&rtype=&fsize=&_use=1&use=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain={0}&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear=2019&repDateWeekly=&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2019&loc=All&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&organic=NO&category=Grain&_mscore=1&subComm=Corn&commodity=Coarse&_commDetail=1&_subprimals=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate={0}&endDate={1}&format=excel'

start = [datetime.date(2018-i, 7, 31) for i in range(20)]
end = [datetime.date(2019-i, 8, 1) for i in range(20)]
for s, e in zip(start, end):
    url_get = url.format(s.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), e.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
    df_lst = pd.read_html(url_get, header=1)

    #print(df_lst[0].head())  # uncomment to see first five rows
    #print(df_lst[0].shape)  # uncomment to see DataFrame shape
```

**Be careful with pd.read_html.** I've modified my answer with a `header` keyword argument to `pd.read_html()` because the multi-indexing made it a pain to get results. By giving a single row index as the header, it's no longer a multi-index, and data indexing is easy. For instance, I can get corn class using this:

```py
df_lst[0]['Class']
```

---

Compiling all the reports into one large file is also easy with Pandas. Since we have a DataFrame, we can use the [pandas.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function to export our data as a CSV (or any other file type you want, but I chose CSV for this example). Here's a modified version with the additional capability of outputting a CSV:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# URL
url = 'https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain={1}&commDetail=All&repMonth=1&endDateWeekly=&repType=Daily&rtype=&fsize=&_use=1&use=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain={0}&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear=2019&repDateWeekly=&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2019&loc=All&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&organic=NO&category=Grain&_mscore=1&subComm=Corn&commodity=Coarse&_commDetail=1&_subprimals=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate={0}&endDate={1}&format=excel'

# CSV output file and flag
csv_out = 'myreports.csv'
flag = True

# Start and end dates
start = [datetime.date(2018-i, 7, 31) for i in range(20)]
end = [datetime.date(2019-i, 8, 1) for i in range(20)]

# Iterate through dates and get report from URL
for s, e in zip(start, end):
    url_get = url.format(s.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), e.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

    df_lst = pd.read_html(url_get, header=1)
    print(df_lst[0].head())  # uncomment to see first five rows
    print(df_lst[0].shape)  # uncomment to see DataFrame shape

    # Save to big CSV
    if flag is True:
        # 0th iteration, so write header and overwrite existing file
        df_lst[0].to_csv(csv_out, header=True, mode='w')  # change mode to 'wb' if Python 2.7
        flag = False
    else:
        # Subsequent iterations should append to file and not add new header
        df_lst[0].to_csv(csv_out, header=False, mode='a')  # change mode to 'ab' if Python 2.7
```

Comment: I get what you have done above. I actually wanted to automate this. I am saying this because I have to extract data for more than 20 years and for different crops. This way I will have to  generate a url each time and then give it to python. Which will make the process lengthy. That's why I was looking into something that Python selects the fields by itself and then extract the excel file

Comment: The URL generation can be done in Python, so it doesn't have to be a manual process. If you include what you want to query I can help show that generation process, too! For instance, you're trying to alter the start date and end date to change the years, right? Are there particular dates you had in mind, or just a year back from the current day? And did you want to go through every option available on the site?

Comment: Yeah. I want to extract this data for corn from January 1992 onwards till July 2019. The website just allows to extract data for one year at a time. Once I understand how this is done, I can try and do it for other crops as well.

Comment: @RaghavGoyal I added an example for iterating through years of data, right now I have it set at 20 but we can go back 27 years too!

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks a lot. I have one question. So, if I am not wrong, all the data is currently stored in df_lst variable. How, do I get this data in one final excel file?

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Yes, all the data is stored in `df_lst`. Technically, it's a list of DataFrame objects, but these reports only give us 1 so I only use that one. Since our data is a DataFrame, exporting to a CSV or Excel file is simple. I added an example to show how I would do that.

Comment: I tried doing this. But it throws me an error: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Ahh I see, it should be fixed now. I had been running on Python 2, but I've updated it to work with Python 3 (changed `'wb'` to `'w'` and `'ab'` to `'a'`). Normal 'w' and 'a' add carriages returns and what-not on Python 2, but that's not a problem on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular query generates at least 1227 pages of data - so I just trimmed it down to one location - Arizona(from 07/31/2018  - 08/1/2019) - now generating 47 pages of data. xml size was 500KB

You can semi automate like this:

```py
>>> end_day='01'
>>> start_day='31'
>>> start_month='07'
>>> end_month='08'
>>> start_year='2018'
>>> end_year='2019'
>>> link = f"https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain={end_month}%2F{end_day}%2F{end_year}&commDetail=All&endDateWeekly={end_month}%2F{end_day}%2F{end_year}&repMonth=1&repType=Daily&rtype=&use=&_use=1&fsize=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain={start_month}%2F{start_day}%2F{start_year}+&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=All+AR&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear={end_year}&repDateWeekly={start_month}%2F{start_day}%2F{start_year}&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear={end_year}&loc=All+AR&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&category=Grain&organic=NO&commodity=Coarse&subComm=Corn&_mscore=0&_subprimals=1&_commDetail=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate={start_month}%2F{start_day}%2F{start_year}&endDate={end_month}%2F{end_day}%2F{end_year}&format=xml"
>>> link
'https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain=08%2F01%2F2019&commDetail=All&endDateWeekly=08%2F01%2F2019&repMonth=1&repType=Daily&rtype=&use=&_use=1&fsize=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain=07%2F31%2F2018+&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=All+AR&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear=2019&repDateWeekly=07%2F31%2F2018&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2019&loc=All+AR&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&category=Grain&organic=NO&commodity=Coarse&subComm=Corn&_mscore=0&_subprimals=1&_commDetail=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate=07%2F31%2F2018&endDate=08%2F01%2F2019&format=xml'

>>> with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as response:
...     html = response.read()
...
```

loading the html could take a hot minute with large queries

If you for some reason wished to process the entire data set - you could repeat this process - but you may wish to look into techniques that can be specifically optimized for big data - perhaps a solution involving Python's Pandas and numexpr(for GPU acceleration/parallelization)

You can find the data used in this answer [here](https://marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain=08%2F01%2F2019&repDate=07%2F31%2F2018%20&commDetail=All&repMonth=1&endDateWeekly=08%2F01%2F2019&repType=Daily&rtype=&fsize=&_use=1&use=&endDate=08%2F01%2F2019&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain=07%2F31%2F2018%20&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=All%20AR&subprimals=&rowDisplayMax=25&mscore=&endYear=2019&repDateWeekly=07%2F31%2F2018&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2019&loc=All%20AR&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&organic=NO&category=Grain&_mscore=0&subComm=Corn&commodity=Coarse&_commDetail=1&_subprimals=1&cut=&endMonth=1&startIndex=1) - which you can download as an xml.

First import your xml:

```py
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

you can either download the file from the website in python

```py
>>> tree = ET.parse(html)
```

or manually

```py
>>> tree = ET.parse('report.xml')
>>> report = tree.getroot()
```

you can then do stuff like this:

```py
>>> report[0][0]
<Element 'reportDate' at 0x7f902adcf368>
>>> report[0][0].text
'07/31/2018'
>>> for el in report[0]:
...     print(el)
... 
<Element 'reportDate' at 0x7f902adcf368>
<Element 'location' at 0x7f902ac814f8>
<Element 'classStr' at 0x7f902ac81548>
<Element 'variety' at 0x7f902ac81b88>
<Element 'grade' at 0x7f902ac29cc8>
<Element 'units' at 0x7f902ac29d18>
<Element 'transMode' at 0x7f902ac29d68>
<Element 'bidLevel' at 0x7f902ac29db8>
<Element 'deliveryPoint' at 0x7f902ac29ea8>
<Element 'deliveryPeriod' at 0x7f902ac29ef8>
```

More info on parsing xml is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).
 You're going to want to learn some python - but hopefully you can make sense of the following. Luckily - there are many free python tutorials online - here is a quick snippet to get you started.

```py
#lets find the lowest bid on a certain day
>>> report[0][0]
<Element 'reportDate' at 0x7f902adcf368>
>>> report[0][0].text
'07/31/2018'
>>> report[0][7]
<Element 'bidLevel' at 0x7f902ac29db8>
>>> report[0][7][0]
<Element 'lowPrice' at 0x7f902ac29e08>
>>> report[0][7][0].text
'3.84'

#how many low bids are there?
>>> len(report)
1216

#get an average of the lowest bids...
>>> low_bid_list = [float(bid[7][0].text) for bid in report]
[3.84, 3.76, 3.74, 3.67, 3.65, 3.7, 3.5, 3.7, 3.61,...]
>>> sum = 0
>>> for el in low_bid_list:
...     sum = sum + el
... 
>>> sum
4602.599999999992
>>> sum/len(report)
3.7850328947368355
```

Comment: Thanks. But again, I am first downloading the excel file and then giving it as an input to python. What I wanted is that Python selects the fields by itself and then use them to run and download excel files. I wanted it this way because I have to extract data for several crops for several years.

Comment: you can keep the autmation shown here and just change format=excel at the end of that link. Then use pandas's read_url as shown in pyNoob's answer.